# Enviar elementos formatados para modal

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite!

Tenho uma lista de números onde o usuário seleciona quais números quer reservar e depois informa seu nome e telefone em um modal, e eu salvo estes dados no banco.

Quando o usuário seleciona mais de um número, eles ficam 'juntos'(ver imagem 1'). Existe uma forma de no script js eu formatar e colocar um estilo(css) nos números e para enviar ao modal já formatado(ver imagem 2)? Ou alguma outra forma?

Imagem 1:

[image: imagem 1]

Imagem 2:

[image]

```js
$('#teste').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
  })

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#mybtn1").click(function() {
          var p=$("#teste #result");
          $.each($("input[name='disponivel']:checked"), function() {
              $(p).html($(p).html() + '  ' + $(this).val());
          });      
      }); 
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


      <div class="modal fade" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservados </h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p id="result"></p>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
<form id="form">
  <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="disponivel">1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="disponivel">2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="disponivel">3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="disponivel">4</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="disponivel">5</li>
  </ul>     
</form>

      <button  id = "mybtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teste" >Reservar números</button>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) com os números dentro de um `span`, e esse `span` você formata no CSS. É preciso também esvaziar a div antes senão irá acumular com o que já tem lá. Para isso você usa [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/).

O CSS do span:

```
#result span{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

Código:

```js
$('#teste').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mybtn1").click(function() {
      var p=$("#teste #result");
      p.empty();
      $.each($("input[name='disponivel']:checked"), function() {
         $(p).append('<span>'+ $(this).val() +'</span>');
      });
   }); 
});
```

```css
#result span{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservados </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p id="result"></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      
<form id="form">
  <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="disponivel">1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="disponivel">2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="disponivel">3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="disponivel">4</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="disponivel">5</li>
  </ul>     
</form>

<button  id = "mybtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teste" >Reservar números</button>
```

Ajuste as bolinhas vermelhas como quiser alterando o `width`, `height`, `line-height` (deve ser igual ao `height` para centralizar verticalmente).

Comment: É exatamente o que preciso! Muito obrigado pela ajuda Sam!